# On Linux, make bootable USB from Windows installation ISO

Tags: linux, windows, iso, bootable

I tried creating a bootable USB from a Windows 10 ISO:

```
dd if=file.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=1M status=progress
```

However, when booting, all I saw was:

```
BOOTMGR is missing.
Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart
```

I can successfully mount the `udf` filesystem on the USB, so the `dd` worked ok.

My BIOS is from 2012.

What magic is required to create a bootable USB key?

Comment: Microsoft made Windows Installation ISO doesn't support that.

Comment: CDs and DVDs use a completely different arrangement for bootability than hard disks and USB keys. Modern Linux ISO images have been specifically prepared (processed with `isohybrid` or similar) to be ready to boot also if transferred to USB media, but apparently Microsoft doesn't do that.

Comment: I've done it using `mint-stick` on a Mint system - on the menu it is titled "USB Image Writer"

Answer (score 2):

Use [WoeUSB](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB) which makes a bootable USB key suitable for old BIOSes. It created a `vfat` partition whereas using `dd` didn't write any partitions.

I used `--workaround-bios-boot-flag` which says:

> Workaround BIOS bug that won't include the device in boot menu if non of the partition's boot flag is toggled

Note also that `--device` will wipe the whole USB key.

Here's my command and output:

```
% sudo woeusb --workaround-bios-boot-flag --device en_windows_10_multiple_editions_x64_dvd_6846432.iso /dev/sdc
WoeUSB v@@WOEUSB_VERSION@@
==============================
Mounting source filesystem...
Wiping all existing partition table and filesystem signatures in /dev/sdc...
/dev/sdc: 5 bytes were erased at offset 0x00008001 (udf): 43 44 30 30 31
Ensure that /dev/sdc is really wiped...
Creating new partition table on /dev/sdc...
Creating target partition...
Making system realize that partition table has changed...
Wait 3 seconds for block device nodes to populate...
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
mkfs.fat: warning - lowercase labels might not work properly with DOS or Windows
Mounting target filesystem...
Applying workaround to prevent 64-bit systems with big primary memory from being unresponsive during copying files.
Copying files from source media...
Installing GRUB bootloader for legacy PC booting support...
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
Installing custom GRUB config for legacy PC booting...
Applying workaround for buggy motherboards that will ignore disks with no partitions with the boot flag toggled
Resetting workaround to prevent 64-bit systems with big primary memory from being unresponsive during copying files.
Unmounting and removing "/media/woeusb_source_1549081699_11951"...
Unmounting and removing "/media/woeusb_target_1549081699_11951"...
You may now safely detach the target device
Done :)
The target device should be bootable now
```

For good measure, type `sync` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

the following worked for me for putting a rhel or centos **.iso** onto a usb stick.

This is done on linux

- plug in usb stick, it shows up **for example** as block device `sdc`
- `cp   windows.iso   /dev/sdc`    {yes, that's it}   {do not copy to `sdc1`, copy to the *block device*}

to undo and make USB stick usable in windows again, because windows won't offer any opportunity to reformat the usb stick after you copy an iso like that, simply do the following on linux

- `parted /dev/sdc mklabel gpt`
- `parted /dev/sdc mkpart primary 0% 100%`
- `mkfs.fat /dev/sdc`
- that will make windows happy and willing to use and/or reformat the udb stick
- change `sdc` to the correct block device which is the usb stick when plugged in, don't mistakenly blow away the wrong disk.

Comment: OP already tried `dd` and it didn't work, in which way is the output of `cp` different?

Answer (score 0):

When this answer is written, it is not possible to install `woeusb` into Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from the PPA, which has been working for some time in older versions of Ubuntu.

But it is possible to use mkusb version 12, mkusb-dus, and mkusb-plug, and you can 'do it yourself'.

See this link and links from it,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive)